# Use PHP to get varchar(max) from MSSQL via ODBC

Tags: linux, php, sql-server, unixodbc

I am trying to fecth a varchar(max) column from a MSSQL server in PHP (on linux) using ODBC but I don't quite get the expected result.

The code:

```
$sqlTest="select convert(text,Contents) as Script from dbo.t_CodeRepository";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sqlTest);
if(!$rs)
{
    echo "Unable to get script contents\n";
}
else
{
    while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
    {
        echo odbc_result($rs,"Script");
    }

}
```

But the output looks like:

```
0x23212f7573722f62696e2f7068700a3c
```

and seems to be limited to 4096 characters.

In my /etc/php.ini I have

```
mssql.textlimit = 1048576
mssql.textsize = 1048576
```

How do I get the entire contents of the field - and converted to normal text, that I can save in a file later on in my script?

Comment: Chaging /etc/php.ini with: 
odbc.defaultlrl = 2000000
seems to solve the issue with the length of the returned row... Now I just need to convert the output to something readable...

Comment: If the column `contents` is a varchar(max) there is no need to convert it to text. Just use `select contents from...`.

Comment: Sean's recommendation makes sense

Comment: I wonder if type casting to TEXT was used due to https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73725